# Django 1.9 and allauth 0.24.1

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have django 1.9

I installed allauth with this [instructions](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). But I have got the following error after running migration:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Error:

```
...
RuntimeError: Model class allauth.account.models.EmailAddress doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded.
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing the `allauth` specific context processors:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                # Required by allauth template tags
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                # allauth specific context processors
                "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
                "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The Django sites framework is required, but you should also add allauth apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ... # here previous existing apps

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    # Login via Google as an exemple, you can choose facebook, twitter as you like
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)
```

I recommend also to set the following parameters to customize the authorization process:

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

You can find more info about the available [settings here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html).

Comment: None of these fix the issue.